# How do I remove the last comma in this range of numbers?(Python)

Tags: python

```
def numbex(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 2
    elif n > 1:
        return numbex(n-1)*(-3)
for num in range(1,11):
    x=numbex(num)
    print(x, end=",")
```

output

```
2,-6,18,-54,162,-486,1458,-4374,13122,-39366,
```

Comment: does your code really print these numbers? numbex function does not always return a number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `sep` parameter of `print`

```
numbers=[numbex(x) for x in range(1,11)]
print(*numbers, sep=",")
```

Answer (score 2):

A nice pythonic way to do is by using `join`:

```
print(','.join([str(numbex(num)) for num in range(1,11)]))
```

The following term: `[str(numbex(num)) for num in range(1,11)]` will create a list, of strings, each string the output of your `numbex` function on a number from `range(1,11)`.

`','.join(...)` will join them to a single string, separating each value by `,`.